# Atualizar campo de tabela com informações de uma outra coluna

Tags: php, mysql

Como fazer um update que recupera os dados de uma coluna e joga em outra coluna?
Por exemplo

Vendas

```
IdVenda | dataVenda  | dataPgto
1       | 2017-08-21 | 
2       | 2017-08-21 |
```

Quero atualizar a dataPgto com a informação de dataVenda? PS: essa venda seria feita com cartão de credito.

Comment: Você precisa dar mais algumas informações, como os nomes e estruturas das tabelas.

Comment: @rLinhares é da mesma tabela irmão :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sendo a mesma tabela você não vai precisar de *join* ou algo do tipo; basta saber a condição de atualização, no caso o *id* do item que será atualizado (*idVendaEfetuada*):

```
UPDATE tabela_vendas SET dataPgto = dataVenda WHERE IdVenda = idVendaEfetuada
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

Basta você fazer o update referenciando uma coluna à outra, exemplo:

`UPDATE vendas SET dataPgto = dataVenda;`

Segue um fiddle com exemplo prático:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5ozLMhyMZXTtQHWD3vzRTK/0